# C# - If I add more methods to a class, will each instance take more space?

Tags: c#, performance

As a programmer you always have the choice to add methods to a class or creating the same method which takes a class instance of that object as an argument.

One way of doing it is like this:

```
List<Car> Oldtimers = new List<Car>();    
class Car { 
   int speed; 
   int size;

   public bool IsBig(){
      return size >5;
   }

   public bool isFast(){
   return speed > 120;
   }
}
```

Or you could also try to save space like that

```
class CarCollection {
   List<Car2> Supercars = new List<Car2>();

    class Car2{ 
        public int speed; 
        public int size;
    }

    bool IsBig(Car2 car){
        return car.size > 5
    }

    bool isFast(Car2 car){
       return car.speed > 120;
    }
}
```

Does a Car2 instance now actually take up less space than Car, because there are no methods attached to it? Which List is better? Is there even a difference in the bytecode?

I would also like to know what the standard is, or if there are some performance issues that I did not see.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: premature optimization is not a good idea. Go for clear and understandable design of your classes and types.

Comment: If putting methods outside a class made its instances take up less space, with no downsides other than clarity, the C# compiler would be written to do just that, even if you logically put the methods inside the class, since it has no need for preserving clarity. The only way it could not is if you could attach and reattach methods to instances at runtime, which is not possible. (Normally -- `dynamic` is quite another beast.) So even from a purely theoretical point of view, you can divine the answer should be "no" in any reasonable world. (Notwithstanding that the world is often unreasonable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a Car2 instance now actually take up less space than Car, b

No.

Each instance has a pointer to its Type, and some other information attached to it.
But that overhead is fixed, even when virtual methods are used.

Only fields take up space inside your instances.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Makes sence

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to save bytes per instance you can switch to a list of structs that store the data and have a manager class that accesses the data like in your example.  The tricky part is when cars are removed.  You could also look at using smaller numeric types like short or byte. Here is an example:

```
public struct CarHandle
{
    internal int m_id;

    internal CarHandle(int id)
    {
        m_id = id;
    }
    public int ID { get { return m_id; } }
}


public class CarManager
{
    private struct CarData
    {
        public int Speed;
        public int Size;
    }

    private List<CarData> m_cars = new List<CarData>();
    private List<int> m_removedCars = new List<int>();

    public CarHandle CreateCar(int speed, int size)
    {
        var carData = new CarData() { Speed = speed, Size = size };
        // see if there is an empty slot we can use
        if (m_removedCars.Count > 0)
        {
            int ix = m_removedCars[m_removedCars.Count - 1];
            m_removedCars.RemoveAt(m_removedCars.Count - 1);
            m_cars[ix] = carData;
            return new CarHandle(ix);
        }
        else
        {
            m_cars.Add(carData);
            return new CarHandle(m_cars.Count-1);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveCar(ref CarHandle handle)
    {
        if (m_cars.Count > handle.ID && m_cars[handle.ID].Size != -1)
        {

            // remove from list if it is the last car in list
            if (handle.ID == m_cars.Count - 1)
            {
                m_cars.RemoveAt(m_cars.Count - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // if we remove this item from the list, it would invalidate 
                // all handles after this index, so we just remember that we 
                // can reuse this slot
                m_removedCars.Add(handle.ID);
                m_cars[handle.ID] = new CarData() { Size = -1, Speed = -1 };
            }
        }
        // invalidate the handle so it cannot be used again
        handle.m_id = -1;
    }

    public int GetSize(CarHandle handle)
    {
        // TODO: add error checking!
        return m_cars[handle.ID].Size;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CarManager manager = new CarManager();
        var car1 = manager.CreateCar(10, 20);
        var s1 = manager.GetSize(car1);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(s1 == 20);
        var car2 = manager.CreateCar(30, 40);
        var s2 = manager.GetSize(car2);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(s2 == 40);

        manager.RemoveCar(ref car1);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(car1.ID == -1);
        s2 = manager.GetSize(car2);

        var car3 = manager.CreateCar(50, 60);
        var s3 = manager.GetSize(car3);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(s3 == 60);
    }
}
```